# Very slow performance

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, performance

I'm using Windows 8.1 RTM with following PC:
[image]

Foxconn h61mxp mb

500gb Seagate ST500DM002 HDD

The problem is, I have nearly always 100% disk load

[image]

Here are running applications on tray:

[image]

And here are startup Applications

[image]

I have Avira antivirus installed. So no virus on HDD. I also checked for hdd errors. No bad sectors or errors found.

I can't find any issue for this much slow performance of PC. What can be issue? Any suggestions?

Comment: Disable Avira and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes your suggestion kinda fixed problem. And what security solution to use?

Comment: Well, that was mostly just to get a clue and not intended as a solution. So the next step is to figure out why Avira is causing you a performance problem. Do you have any other scanners installed and enabled that might conflict with it (like Windows Defender or Microsoft Security Essentials)? Have you changed its configuration from the defaults?

Comment: Almost every single one of your programs have a high impact on your startup.  Try disabling them all and see if your performance increases.

Comment: If you continue to use Avira you **need** to disable "Windows Defender" in Windows 8. It is **not** advised to have multiple anti-virus solutions installed on your system. On Windows 8 "Windows Defender" is activated as default. See [here](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/21962-windows-defender-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) how you can disable it.